# read lines of text file to string array

Tags: inputstream, outputstream

I need to write lines of text into a file and then read them line by line.
therefore I used these codes to write into a file:

```
String string = "Hello world55555555555!" + "\r\n";
FileOutputStream outputStream;


try {
    outputStream = getActivity().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}



return true;
```

which it seems work properly. but when I am reading it get error! I am trying to read it by these codes:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
BufferedReader reader;
String[] text = new String[0];
List < String > words = new ArrayList < String > ();
String line;
try {
    inputStream = getActivity().openFileInput(filename);
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        words.add(line);
    }

    text = new String[words.size()];
    text = words.toArray(text);

} catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}

tv.setText(text[0]);


Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text[1],
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

any comments! Please!

Comment: Any time you “get error” [Please tell us the error message](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabflavor/article/please_please_please/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your considerations, I update my read codes to:

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    BufferedReader reader;
    StringBuilder[] total = new StringBuilder[]{};
    String line;
    try{ 
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        int j =0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            total[j].append(line);
            j++;
        }



    }
    catch(IOException e){
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }

    tv.setText(total[0]);


    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),total[1],
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But I get errors yet and app shutdown:

```
10-18 10:36:50.700    3087-3087/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-18 10:36:50.700    3087-3087/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ir.siavashon.sunshine, PID: 3087
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at ir.siavashon.sunshine.MainActivityFragment.onClick(MainActivityFragment.java:140)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        10-18 10:36:50.700    1342-2903/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity ir.siavashon.sunshine/.MainActivity
        10-18 10:36:50.710      993-993/? D/gralloc﹕ Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
        10-18 10:36:50.710      993-993/? E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
        10-18 10:36:50.710      993-993/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -906983389
        10-18 10:36:50.710      993-993/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
        10-18 10:36:50.730    1342-3103/? W/DropBoxManagerService﹕ Dropping: data_app_crash (848 > 0 bytes)
        10-18 10:36:51.220    1342-1356/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{a21f483 u0 ir.siavashon.sunshine/.MainActivity t897 f}
        10-18 10:36:52.190    1656-1656/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
        10-18 10:36:53.330    3087-3087/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3087 SIG: 9
        10-18 10:36:53.430    1342-1372/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel 'cb217a9 ir.siavashon.sunshine/ir.siavashon.sunshine.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
        10-18 10:36:53.430    1342-1372/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel 'cb217a9 ir.siavashon.sunshine/ir.siavashon.sunshine.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
        10-18 10:36:53.430    1342-2903/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process ir.siavashon.sunshine (pid 3087) has died
        10-18 10:36:53.590    1342-1361/? W/AppOps﹕ Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
        10-18 10:36:53.600    1342-1490/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{cb217a9 u0 ir.siavashon.sunshine/ir.siavashon.sunshine.MainActivity}
        10-18 10:36:53.600    1342-1490/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'cb217a9 ir.siavashon.sunshine/ir.siavashon.sunshine.MainActivity (server)'
```